# Writing XML to Variable

Tags: vb.net, svg, xmlwriter

I want to create a XML (SVG) "file" within my program. I used the XMLWriter to create the SVG file now I want to save the created file in a variable within the program for later use (showing the SVG file in a webbrowser in my windowsform). Does anyone have an idea how to make it write to a variable instead of a file? I did manage getting it to a file but I dont want to use an external file.

If this is not possible, could it be an idea to save the file to a local temporary folder on the users PC and then inmeddiatly retrieve it back to the program?

EDIT:
So I took a look at the Xdocument, and I get the idea but I have no clue how to enter it in my code.

Here is a snippet of my code where I think It should be

```
 'my variable which i want my SVG saved in
    Public Xdoc As XDocument

    'part of the sub that creates the XML/SVG file
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings With {
        .Indent = True
    }

            Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(XmlLocation, settings)

    With XmlWrt

        ' Write the Xml declaration.
        .WriteStartDocument()

        ' Write a comment.
        .WriteComment("XML Database.")

        ' Write the root element.
        .WriteStartElement("svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

        'atributes in elemenent + namespace
        .WriteAttributeString("viewBox", "0 0 " & SVGWidth & " " & SVGheight)
        .WriteAttributeString("width", "100%")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xlink", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")


   ' A load of code that writes the content of the XML/SVG

' here it ends the SVG element. 
        .WriteEndElement()

        ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()

    End With
```

Does someone have an idea how to instead of writing to XMLlocation I can write to the Xdocument?

Comment: Take a look at classes: `XmlDocument` and `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got this working now: used the following code

```
'XML settings and location
    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Xdoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())

    With XmlWrt

            ' Write the Xml declaration.
            .WriteStartDocument()
```